# SSL Certificate installed successfully but website not accessible

Tags: ssl, windows-server-2012-r2, ssl-certificate, azure, iis-8.5

I have installed Let's Encrypt SSL Certificate on a windows-server-2012-r2 machine running iis-8.5. It is an ASP.NET 4.5 website running on an Azure VM.

The installation was successful and I can see the https binding for the website.

However the website is accessible on http, but not https. I have recycled the AppPool but in vain. I have also added an inbound rule in Azure portal for port 443.

What could be the reason? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Generate a report first, and then you can see what might be the issue https://www.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having the certificate doesn't automatically switch to https, it merely enables https. SO first you should verify that https indeed works. If you want to enforce https, setup a redirection from http to https.